# Value of type '1-dimensional array of System.Collections.Hashtable' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Hashtable

Tags: vb.net, hashtable

I am using a hastable but when i add a value to it i get an error

**Value of type '1-dimensional array of System.Collections.Hashtable' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Hashtable'**

Am i missing missing really basic.

```
  Public Shared Function LstItemsAsHT() As Hashtable()

        Dim htStudents As Hashtable = New Hashtable()

        Try
            Using dbcontext As New Entities
                Dim result = From l In dbcontext.students
                             Where l.Pass = False
                              Select l

                For Each student In result.ToList()
                    htReceipt.Add(student.Id, student.Type)

                Next
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        Return htStudents 

    End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have it working with Dictionary(Of Int32, String) , but need it working with hastable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method returns a `HashTable()` instead of a single `HashTable`. Change it to:

```
Public Shared Function LstItemsAsHT() As Hashtable
```

Apart form that, why do you still use a `Hashtable` at all if you can use a strong typed `Dictionary(Of Int32, String)`? Also, the `result.ToList()` is not needed. You can enumerate the sequence immediately without creating a new list first.